# Why does white space appear when I remove these elements?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

In the menu section I have a design of triangles on the left and right side of the page. When the screen gets to the width of 775px I set a media query and make these designs disappear with display: none; When I do this white space appears on the right side?? Any Ideas on what's causing the problem? I can't find anything in my devtools https://jsfiddle.net/ampvogje/1/

```js
const ham = document.querySelector('.nav-box');
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
const menuClose = document.querySelector('#menu-close');
const leftArrow = document.querySelector('#left');
const rightArrow = document.querySelector('#right');
const img = document.querySelector('.image-slider');
let num = 1;


ham.addEventListener('click', function() {
 ham.classList.add('ham-open');
 menu.style.marginLeft = '50px';
})

menuClose.addEventListener('click', function() {
 ham.classList.remove('ham-open');
 menu.style.marginLeft = '-700px';
})

leftArrow.addEventListener('click', function() {
 num--;
 if(num > 0) {
  img.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/fam-' + num + '.jpeg)';
  console.log(num);
  console.log(img.style.backgroundImage);
 } else {
  num = 4;
  img.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/fam-' + num + '.jpeg)';
 }
})

rightArrow.addEventListener('click', function() {
 num++;
 if(num <= 4) {
  img.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/fam-' + num + '.jpeg)';
  console.log(num);
  console.log(img.style.backgroundImage);
 } else {
  num = 1;
  img.style.backgroundImage = 'url(img/fam-' + num + '.jpeg)';
 } 
})

// window.sr = ScrollReveal();

// sr.reveal('.logo-wrap', {
//  duration: 2000
// });

// sr.reveal('.w1', {
//  duration: 2000,
//  origin: 'bottom'
// });

// sr.reveal('.w2', {
//  duration: 3000,
//  origin: 'bottom'
// });

// sr.reveal('.w3', {
//  duration: 4000,
//  origin: 'bottom'
// });

// sr.reveal('.hours-line-left', {
//  duration: 1000,
//  origin: 'left',
//  distance: '200px'
// });

// sr.reveal('.hours-line-right', {
//  duration: 1000,
//  origin: 'right',
//  distance: '200px'
// });

// sr.reveal('.contact-line', {
//  duration: 1000,
//  origin: 'bottom',
//  distance: '250px'
// });

// sr.reveal('.burrito', {
//  duration: 1000,
//  origin: 'right',
//  distance: '250px'
// });

// sr.reveal('.taco', {
//  duration: 1000,
//  origin: 'right',
//  distance: '250px'
// });

// sr.reveal('.guac', {
//  duration: 1000,
//  origin: 'right',
//  distance: '250px'
// });

// sr.reveal('.nachos', {
//  duration: 1000,
//  origin: 'bottom',
//  distance: '250px'
// });

// sr.reveal('.hot', {
//  duration: 1000,
//  origin: 'left',
//  distance: '250px'
// });

// sr.reveal('.back-to-top', {
//  duration: 1000,
//  origin: 'bottom',
// });

// sr.reveal('.btp-arrow', {
//  duration: 1500,
//  origin: 'top',
//  distance: '250px'
// });
```

p.s the code in the snippet is only there so I can post the fiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

Basically `.food-wrap` and "Authentic Mexican Food" label, maybe something else too. Check white space with Element Inspector in the browser (or delete sections one after another) or add an 1px border to every `div {...}` and see what makes content overflow.

Comment: But how come the white space only appears when I remove the designs in the 775px media query? When I comment that out the whitespace doesn't appear? If it was .`.food-wrap` or ""Authentic Mexican Food" shouldn't I see the white space regardless if the design is there or not?? I also did try an outline and the element inspector. But got nothing.

Comment: You have .food-wrap { right: -20px; } for max-width:775px and that's what cause white space, at least as I see it in your fiddle example. And if you make the screen even smaller then 775px, white space will grow because of a label at the top (and maybe something else).